# Using Html input pattern (500/600)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jsp

I want the following pattern in my Html text box : 500/600
i Have wriiten the following html code for it but its wrong

```
<input type="text" placeholder="eg: 500/600"  name="txtShscpercent" pattern="[0-9]+\.[0-9]+[{\|\}]+[0-9]+" required></td>
```

can anyone help me with this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the behavior you are currently getting? What behavior to you want to the pattern to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Whole numbers:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="eg: 500/600"  name="txtShscpercent" pattern="\d+\/\d+" required>
```

Decimals:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="eg: 500/600"  name="txtShscpercent" pattern="\d+(\.\d+)?\/\d+(\.\d+)?" required>
```

Comment: *Gud One*    `:) :D`